# Redirection of a specific page according to the language of the browser .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, multilingual

I want redirect user with english navigator and specific page to another page.

If navigator is english and this page is open :
https://example.com/enregistrement

I need redirect user to :
https://example.com/en/registry

my .htaccess actually but not working :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/enregistrement/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/en/registry/ [R,L]
```

In second time i need make the same in es,de,it,...

Its first time I am working on htaccess at all!

Many thanks!

Comment: Your `.htaccess` looks "OK", except that you have included a trailing slash in the rule, but there is no trailing slash in your example? However, the order of the rules in your `.htaccess` file can be important... where exactly have you put it? Also, detecting the language in this way is not particularly accurate/reliable.

Comment: Ordering languages in the `Accept-Language` header by descending preference factor is just a convention AFAIK, but not required behavior. So just checking "starts with" might not be enough to handle this properly in the first place.